# How to use specified key when working with github via portablegit?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have two ssh keys to work with github - my own and one from organisation where I'm working.
My key was generated automatically by github gui client and the other one was generated by portablegit. 
My .ssh folder looks like:

```
github_rsa            <--- my key
github_rsa.pub
id_rsa                <--- org key
id_rsa.pub
```

When I use portablegit it takes the key with name 'id_rsa' but sometimes I need to use my key too. How can I setup default key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can by adding to your `HOME/.ssh` a `config` file:

```
Host wpengine 
user git
hostname git.wpengine.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myPrivateKey
```

You can add as many 'Host' entry as you want, each one with a different `IdentityFile`

See for instance "[Multiple SSH Keys settings for different github account](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996)"

```
#activehacker account
Host github.com-activehacker
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_activehacker

#jexchan account
Host github.com-jexchan
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_jexchan
```

You can then use the scp syntax for cloning your repo:

```
git clone github.com-activehacker:activehacker/gfs.git gfs_jexchan
```

(instead of `ssh://git@github.com/activehacker/gfs.git`, which wouldn't be able to reference a specific private key and would always fall back to `id_rsa`.)