# Unable to add ssh-key of EC2 instance to bitbucket account

Tags: git, ssh, amazon-ec2, rsa, bitbucket

I want to clone a repository to an EC2 instance I'm using. I generated ssh key pair using "ssh-keygen".

```
Your public key has been saved in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa2.pub.
```

the id_rsa2.pub looks something like:

```
ssh-rsa a_very_long_sequence ubuntu@ip-a-b-c-d
```

I pasted the key as it is to the keys associated with my bit bucket account. But I'm being prompted

```
Invalid SSH key (ssh-keygen).
```

Comment: Did you find out what the problem was?

Comment: @TTT : Yes, but sorry I don't remember. Been a long time!!

Answer (score 4):

So what might be a problem is that you add your SSH-key as the `ubuntu` user, but you `git clone` the repository with `sudo`.

So what you need to do, if you use `sudo git clone git@bitbucket.org:username/repo.git`, you need to get the `id_rsa.pub` from the root user and add it to Bitbucket (or Git?):

```
sudo su - root  # switch to root user
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub  # create if not already existing
sudo su - ubuntu  # switch back to normal user
```

Now I can pull/clone from my repository without password authentication.

Answer (score 2):

.ssh/id_rsa2.pub isn't the default name an ssh session will look for to pass to the server.

Try and rename your keys in

```
.ssh/id_rsa
.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Or use a [`~/.ssh/config` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18527159/6309) to point to the right private/public keys.