# Not able to connect to bitbucket using git ssh in EC2 Ubuntu instance

Tags: git, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh, bitbucket

I'm trying to connect git using SSH on ubuntu EC2 instance.

I tried with following steps, I'm getting public key error.

- Generated SSH using command **ssh-keygen** and added that key in bitbucket.
- Edited ~username/.ssh/authorized_keys and added key generated.
- when i run command **ssh -T git@bitbucket.org**, i see following result,

  ```
  logged in as user-name

  You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
  ```
- If i do git pull in project directory , I'm getting error

  ```
  git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
  ```

Help me to get rid of this error.

Note : I tried with following solution, it didn't work.
[git push origin master: permission denied (public key) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179896/git-push-origin-master-permission-denied-public-key-error)

**Note** (Updated) :: It works in my local machine(windows) with SSH key.

Comment: Is your key listed in `ssh-add -L`?

Comment: Yeah it shows my key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with following solution, it worked.

```
sudo su - root  # switch to root user
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub  # create if not already existing
sudo su - ubuntu  # switch back to normal user
```

This is referred from [Unable to add ssh-key of EC2 instance to bitbucket account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822433/unable-to-add-ssh-key-of-ec2-instance-to-bitbucket-account)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change the permission of keys and folder.

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

You may also need to change the permissions of your home directory and remove write access for the group and others.

```
chmod go-w ~
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6377073/9907481) helped me answer your question.

Comment: If key permissions were the problem then that'd cause an error in the `ssh git@bitbucket.org` tests.

Comment: @amsh it is not working, still I'm getting public key error.