# Git Pull from Openshift using Windows: Invalid refspec

Tags: windows, git, ssh-keys, openshift

I created a PHP application on [Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/) and successfully SSH into my app. My Git repository on Openshift is similar to this: `ssh://1234567890@my_app_name.rhcloud.com/~/git/app_name.git/` . I also created a local Git repository on my computer. I saved my public and private keys here (relative to my local repo): `../ssh/`. I named the public and private keys like this: `.ssh` and `.ssh.pub` I'm trying to Git pull from my Openshift repo with the following:

```
git pull ssh:../ssh/.ssh 1234567890@my_app_name.rhcloud.com/~/git/app_name.git/
fatal: Invalid refspec '1234567890@my_app_name.rhcloud.
com/~/git/app_name.git/'
```

But I'm getting this error `fatal: Invalid refspec`.

I also tried

```
git pull ssh://1234567890@my_app_name.rhcloud.com/~/git/app_name.git/
```

But I got the following error

> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic). fatal:
>   Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

How do I pull from Openshift using ssh on Windows?

PS: I created these keys using Git's `ssh-keygen -t rsa`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a [`.ssh/config file`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18527159/6309) which will reference your private key.

```
Host upstream
    HostName my_app_name.rhcloud.com
    User 1234567890
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/.ssh
```

Then use the SCP syntax for ssh url:

```
git pull upstream:~/git/app_name.git/
```