# Git with putty on windows

Tags: windows, git, ssh, putty

When attempting to push / pull over ssh, git is failing with the following error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" push -u --recurse-submodules=check -progress "testremote" project:project
Using username "git-receive-pack 'ec2-user".
FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
Done
```

The remote "testremote" is setup as "ssh://ec2-user@sweeb.net:gittest.git" and I'm using an existing keypair that I have used with PuTTY before without issue.

Pageant is running, with my key loaded.

I think the issue is the line "Using username "git-receive-pack 'ec2-user"." - I assumed git's commands were breaking on windows thanks to the space in "Program Files" so I've tried to surround everything with double quotes, but that doesn't seem to be working. Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Windows vars:

```
GIT_SSH=C:\PuTTY\plink.exe
PATH=[...];"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd";"C:\Program Files\Git\libexec\git-core\";"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\"
```

Comment: Would `ssh://ec2-user@sweeb.net/gittest.git` works better? ('`/`' instead of '`:`'). '`:`' is the SCP syntax and supposes a config file as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18909539/6309.

Comment: is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by removing "ssh://", that's implicit in Git Extensions apparently.